# Error: The type or namespace AdvancedTextBoundary could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compiler-errors, visual-c#-express-2010

I have this line of code:

```
public AdvancedTextBoundary TextBoundary { get; set; }
```

Which gets this error:

```
Error:  The type or namespace AdvancedTextBoundary could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly refrence?)
```

The answer is probably something very simple, but I searched both StackOverflow and Google, and there was nothing.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What is the purpose of this class? where you got reference? Is it class inside your project?

Comment: @Learner the class is a public abstract class inside my project.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @cullub You're probably just missing a `using` statement. Put your cursor on `AdvancedTextBoundary` in the snippet you've posted here and press `ctrl` + `.`. Selecting the top option in the context menu should add the using statement for you.

Comment: If there is an assembly reference needed for doing this, that would probably fix my problem

Comment: The error is very obvious. If you have the correct assembly referenced, right click on `AdvancedTextBoundary` -> `Resolve` ->  `using ...`. If you don't see that option, you don't have the assembly in which this class lives referenced.

Comment: @JasonP your comment fixed my problem.  Put it in an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange you are correct.  It is very obvious... *after the fact*.  Your first sentence was probably not necessary, though.

Comment: Hey - Why the downvote?  I asked a question because I did not understand.  I had done research, yet did not find the answer.  So I figured that StackOverflow (and myself) could benefit by having one more answer to the worlds questions.  We need to label our down(and up)votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `using` statement because the `AdvancedTextBoundary` class and the class in which you've added a property of that type are in different namespaces.

You can let Visual Studio add the reference for you by placing your cursor on `AdvancedTextBoundary`, pressing `ctrl` + `.`, and then hitting enter or selecting the top option with your mouse.

Note that if you're missing a reference to an assembly or project, the context menu won't have the option to add the `using` statement, it will instead give you the option to create a new stub of a class with that name. In that case, you'll need to add the reference first.